# Python Tuple Operation - Get Value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple that contains province data.

```
CHOICES = (
        ('', ''),
        ('United States', (
                ('AL', 'Alabama'),
                ('AK', 'Alaska'),
                ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
                ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
                ('CA', 'California'),
                ('CO', 'Colorado'),
                ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
                ('DE', 'Delaware'),
                ('DC', 'District of Columbia'),
                ('FL', 'Florida'),
                ('GA', 'Georgia'),
                ('GU', 'Guam'),
                ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
                ('ID', 'Idaho'),
                ('IL', 'Illinois'),
                ('IN', 'Indiana'),
                ('IA', 'Iowa'),
                ('KS', 'Kansas'),
                ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
                ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
                ('ME', 'Maine'),
                ('MD', 'Maryland'),
                ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
                ('MI', 'Michigan'),
                ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
                ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
                ('MO', 'Missouri'),
                ('MT', 'Montana'),
                ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
                ('NV', 'Nevada'),
                ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
                ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
                ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
                ('NY', 'New York'),
                ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
                ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
                ('OH', 'Ohio'),
                ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
                ('OR', 'Oregon'),
                ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
                ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
                ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
                ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
                ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
                ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
                ('TX', 'Texas'),
                ('UT', 'Utah'),
                ('VT', 'Vermont'),
                ('VA', 'Virginia'),
                ('VI', 'Virgin Islands'),
                ('WA', 'Washington'),
                ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
                ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
                ('WY', 'Wyoming')
            )
        ),
        ('Canada', (
                ('AB', 'Alberta' , 1.05),
                ('BC', 'British Columnbia', 1.12),
                ('MB', 'Manitoba', 1.05),
                ('NB', 'New Brunswick', 1.13),
                ('NL', 'Newfoundland and Labrador', 1.13),
                ('NT', 'Northwest Territories', 1.05),
                ('NS', 'Nova Scotia', 1.15),
                ('NU', 'Nunavut', 1.05),
                ('PE', 'Prince Edward Island', 1.05),
                ('SK', 'Saskatchewan', 1.05),
                ('ON', 'Ontario', 1.13),
                ('QC', 'Quebec', 1.05),
                ('YT', 'Yukon', 1.05)
            )
        )
    )
```

Is there an elegant way of getting the the number based on the province code if a Canadian province is selected.  example.  If I have the province ON is there a tuple operation that I can use to get the value 1.13.

Thanks.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure here. You want a dictionary, not a tuple.

Comment: `[y[2] for x in CHOICES if x[0] == "Canada" for y in x[1] if y[0] == "ON"][0]` is the most elegant expression you're going to get, unless you use a dictionary. With a `dict`, that could be `CHOICES["Canada"]["ON"][1]`.

Comment: Accept more answers to past questions.

Answer (score 3):

The comments highlight your main problem -- the unfortunate data structure. You can, however, easily convert your nested tuple into a dict. On Python >=2.7:

```
>>> choices = {country: {t[0]: t[1:] for t in st} for country, st in CHOICES}
>>> choices['Canada']['ON'][1]
1.13
```

Note: This will make `choices['United States']` dict contain one-element tuples as values.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Canada={CHOICES[2][1][x][0]:CHOICES[2][1][x][2]for x in range(len(a[2][1]))}
   Canada["ON"]
```